# "ShadowLastChange" attribute doesn't work

Tags: openldap

I installed the following Openldap version on Centos 7 Server:

```
ldapsearch: @(#) $OpenLDAP: ldapsearch 2.4.40 (Mar 31 2016 15:24:47) $
    mockbuild@worker1.bsys.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.40/openldap-2.4.40/clients/tools
    (LDAP library: OpenLDAP 20440)
```

My Client is Centos 7 too.

Everything is working properly less one thing, when "ShadowLastChange" is set to "0" to force expiring the password.

I am prompted change the password and the password is changed and the ShadowLastChange is changed as well but when I try to login again I am prompted change the password on every login:

```
You are required to change your password immediately (password aged)
password expired 16560 days ago
Last login: Thu Sep 15 22:14:19 2016 
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user test.ldap.
(current) LDAP Password: 
New password:
```

I read the following link related to this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/215196/not-able-to-update-shadowlastchange-value-for-ldap

My shadowLastChange attribute on nis.schema is alright:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.5 NAME 'shadowLastChange'
        EQUALITY integerMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

Also, my shadowLAstChanged attribute is changed by changing password but still prompting change password on every login.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Same on ubuntu 16.04. 
Workaround - I added the line to /etc/ldap.conf.

```
nss_default_attribute_value  shadowLastChange 20000
```